# How do I make the Cycles world background a vertical gradient?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Blender render has a nice vertical gradient for the background. I cannot find a vertical gradient background in the cycles render, only a horizontal gradient. How can I use a vertical gradient as the Cycles world background?

Cycles render horizontal gradient:[image: 1]

Vertical blender render gradient:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the node editor.
Set the shader type to world and select *Use Nodes*:

[image]

Add a *Texture Coordinate* node, a *Separate XYZ*, two *Math* nodes and a *Colorramp* node.

Connect the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node to the *Separate XYZ* node, the *Z* output to the first *math* node, change the type of the *math* node to *Add* and set the bottom value to 1, connect the output of the first *Math* node to the second *Math* node, set the type of that node to *Multiply*, and leave the bottom value at 0.5. Connect the output of the *Multiply* node to the *Colorramp* node and connect the *Colorramp* node to the *Color* input of the *Background* node.

[image]

This will give the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was actually the first time I used the node system. This is so much better than using the menus to get the effect I wanted

Comment: Am I the only one that is still having trouble with this?  This solution just makes it so the background changes colors when I look at it from different angles.

Comment: @Alex the background in this case is the sky, the inside of a sphere, and not a simple plane that is put as a background behind the object.

Comment: @Ezra My issue was that my camera was set to orthographic projection, so I couldn't get any gradients.  Still don't know how to fix!

Comment: How does one go to the node editor in 2.8? The buttons in your first screenshot don't seem to appear anywhere on my screen.

Comment: I found it. In 2.8: go to the "shading" tab at the top, then, about halfway down the screen, click where it says "object". This brings up a drop-down. Select "world".

Answer (score 16):

One way to make the world a vertical gradient in Cycles is to add a [*Gradient texture*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/gradient.html#gradient-texture-node) and [*color ramp*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/color_ramp.html#color-ramp-node) for your color, and rotate the texture coordinates accordingly.

Here is the node setup and result of said nodes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you easily convert it to a radial gradient?