# How do you create a Gradient Texture as the background for your world?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, world

Actually, I have the answer to this, I have just found it at the time of posting this thread, as a matter of fact. I want to point out that a ColorRamp node will actually do the trick, but this will be different from how I ran into the eye gradient texture, seeing as legitimate image textures are not present here.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60480/how-do-i-make-the-cycles-world-background-a-vertical-gradient

Answer (score 1):

As promised, I intend to answer, once and for all, how to attain a gradient texture for world backgrounds. I had found myself searching through a few Blender Stack Exchange threads, and *this* one in particular did the trick:

[Cycles texture mapping, generated coordinates with world orientation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7222/cycles-texture-mapping-generated-coordinates-with-world-orientation/7223#7223)

[image: Gradient Texture World Node setup]

If you check that link to a different Blender Stack Exchange thread, you will notice the same setup being used for an object. I had previously overlooked that, believing it to be impossible for use with World Nodes.

...I was wrong.

Not *only* could you use that node setup to achieve a gradient background, you can also use a Mapping node, personally best set to point, in order to rotate, scale and position it as you please. Here, see for yourself:

[image: Resulting example]

Using Normal allows you to properly use Rotation to legitimately rotate the gradient, though it does not seem to stay linear. Using a Gradient Texture node does not work with any of these nodes, as far as I have currently determined.

[image: Rotation example]

Edit: By setting scale as seen here, I have managed to straighten the gradient, but it only works at certain angles.
[image: Straightened gradient.]

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you wish. Just click the little check mark to the left of your answer