# Why is my World shader with a gradient in 2.8 only showing some of the colours in my colour ramp?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, world

I would like to set the 'world' shader to a gradient, which should be one colour at the nadir, another colour at the zenith, and other colours in between, using a ColorRamp node.

There is an answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60488/87587), but it's for an older version of Blender and doesn't seem to behave quite as described in 2.8. I do get a gradient, but no matter how much I fiddle with it, I can't seem to get it to cover the whole range of the ColorRamp.

There are also various answers covering how to get a gradient across the window, but that's not what I want. I'm aiming for more of a sky dome sort of effect.

This is my current set-up, which isn't quite working - it seems to be correct in the upper half of the sky, but the lower half is a uniform yellow-green.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: @RayMairlot my question is literally what the title says: how do you achieve a sky gradient in Blender 2.8? If there is something you feel is missing, which would make it more specific in a way you would find more satisfying while also accurately representing my question, then by all means please go ahead and hit the edit button, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for myself after a bit more fiddling around. I'm not quite sure what I was doing wrong, but I figured I'd post this for others, because it's somewhat simpler than the setup in the linked question.

[image]

Comment: Recommend try the new sky texture (added to 2.90) for a better result: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Cycles#Sky_Texture

Comment: @brockmann thanks - I'll use it for sure if I need a realistic sky. In this case I was trying to achieve a specific non-natural look, so I needed the extra control of a ColorRamp